# Text breaking onto next line in before end of line of UITextView when rotated

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, uitextview, cgaffinetransform

I trying to create a text view, rotate, it and show some text in it.  I can create and rotate the UITextView, but the text is breaking onto next line before the end of the line in my UITextView.

```
    let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
    textView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)
    textView.text = "This is some long sample text to show the issue I am facing.  Notice that the text is broken onto the next line well before the end of the UITextView."
    
    textView.backgroundColor = .red
    textView.center = view.center
    
    view.addSubview(textView)
```

**Issue:**

[image: Issue]

---

**Identifying the issue**

However, the text does not break to the next line before the end of the UITextView if I don't rotate the textview (by commenting out the following line from above).  So, the issue seems to be caused by rotating the image, but I do not understand why or how to resolve the issue.

```
textView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi / 2)
```

---

**Why the text is breaking onto the next line in middle of UITextView only when rotated and how can this issue be resolved?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent this issue by doing the following:

1. Create a new view (myView)
2. Create the text view (myTextView)
3. Add myTextView to myView
4. Rotate myView

---

```
// create a new view
let myView = UITextView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.height-200, height: view.frame.width-200)) // this frame will have 100px margin on the top & bottom as well as on the left & right once rotated

// create a new textview
let myTextView = UITextView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollOutlet.frame.height-messageMarginTop*2, height: scrollOutlet.frame.width-messageMarginLeft*2))
myTextView.text = "This is some long sample text to show the resolved issue. Notice that the text will no longer be broken onto the next line before the end of the UITextView.. Enjoy!"

// add the new text view to the myView
myView.addSubview(myTextView)

// rotate the myView
myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/2)

// center myView in ViewController's view
myView.center.x = view.center.x
myView.center.y = view.center.y

self.view.addSubview(myView)
```